# Lazy loading class not loading - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have clients:

```
public class Client
{
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

And projects:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
}
```

The client controller has a details get action:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    Client client = db.Clients.Find(id);
    return View(client);
}
```

And a details post action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(Client client)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
                    // reload object from db to populate projects property
        client = db.Clients.Find(client.ClientID);
    }
    return View(client);
}
```

My client details view:

```
@model Client
<h1>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ClientName)</h1>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Client</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClientID)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClientName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<h2>Projects</h2>

<ul>
@foreach (Project project in Model.Projects)
{
    <li>@Html.ActionLink(project.ProjectName, "Details", "Project", new { id = project.ProjectID }, null)</li>
}
</ul>
```

Now if I go to a client which has projects, it works fine, I see the client name in the textbox, and a list of projects. I edit the name and click Save. But then the view errors on the subclass list iteration, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I added in this line specifically to reload the instance from the db, assuming it would then repopulate the lazy-loading list class, and I would have the same instance data as I had in the get request, just with the name changed:

```
client = db.Clients.Find(client.ClientID);
```

Why is it not loading the subclass on the postback?

Once I have this fixed, would it be a good idea in the Client class, to add a constructor that instantiates the List class, in case I navigate to a Client that doesn't have any records in the database?

Comment: where is `db` initialised?

Comment: @qujck - in the ClientController

Comment: Are you sure your modification is saved in the DB ? Because the client argument of your action is a "model class" (not an entity proxy class imho) generated by the model binder according to your action signature. And as the client class does not have a contructor initializing Projects, Projects get the default value: null.

Comment: @tschmit007 Yes, definitely saved. In fact, if I replaced the "Find" line with a "return RedirectToAction" of the Client Details, then it works perfectly. But I would prefer not to have a redirect, as then I have to pass an "updated" message in the querystring. Why can't I just return the view with the updated model.

Comment: well, it seems that Entry attach the objet to the context without loading it. That is why you have to reload the entity (to enable lazy loading) after the update. The classic way is to load the entity before the update. For this you may use [ApplyCurrentValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487246.aspx) or another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to have to look into ApplyCurrentValues, but for the moment, this is how I've got it to work:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(Client client)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { msg = "saved" });
        }
        client.Projects = db.Clients.Find(client.ClientID).Projects;
        return View(client);
    }
```

The Projects are re-attached if the validation fails, before being passed back to the view. In theory, this should work instead of an Action redirect. I'll try that out too.

Comment: Another option here would be to use a partial view, and pass into that view a model of just the projects direct from the database, so it's not coming from the updated model instance.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that on post MVC is constructing an instance of the actual POCO, *NOT* an instance of the proxy class that derives from the POCO.  Therefore, there is no overridden virtual property to perform the lazy loading.

The solution is to explicitly load the collection via the entry (to replace your Clients.Find(id) call):

```
db.Entry(client).Collection( c => c.Projects ).Load();
```

Answer (score 0):

The line you have added to reload the client will not do anything as the context already has a local copy of the client. You could prove this by eager loading the client/project before making the update. (something like this)

```
client = db.Clients.Find(client.ClientID);
client.Projects.ToList();
db.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. If I debug it: Before the save, it doesn't have projects. After the save, still no projects. After my force-reload (Find) - still no projects.

Comment: using `ICollection` means that EF can provide whatever class it likes, `List` means it must be a `List`

Comment: Won't that overwrite the change in client (ClientName), received from the postback?